# Adding user to local PC before they've signed in

Tags: windows, user-accounts, active-directory

Is there any way to add a network user's user directory to the C:\Users folder prior to them having signed in?

If you attempt to manually add a folder into the machine with their account name, when they sign in it will give them a separate location named user.DOMAIN.

The only reason I am curious is that it would simplify my workflow at times if I were able to transfer a user's data prior to them having to sign into the new PC.

Comment: Try reading this: https://serverfault.com/a/75160/372623

Comment: I would guess in lieu of NewDomain.Account, for you it would be Account.NewDomain

Comment: I assume that you are hoping to copy their pertinent files/folders over the network via a "**c$**" share. Previously, my team has mitigated this problem one of two ways:  we can make a folder with the new user's name inside `C:\Users\Public\Downloads` and then copy their Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Music, Pictures, and Video folders there. After they login for the first time, copy the contents to their *real* user folders. Conversely, add them to the new machine's `Remote Desktop Users` local group and have the user RDP into the new machine to create their user profile folder.

Comment: Wouldn't asking for their password be feasible, so you can login yourself? They can always change it afterwards. Or reset the password when necessary. It's not like as a network admin you don't have access to all their stuff anyways.

Comment: It's against our policy to request their password, not just because of their data, but because of what can be accessed with their credentials.

Comment: @QMord If they have never logged into the machine then their files do not exist on that machine.  Sounds like you want roaming domain profiles.

Comment: @QMord if your goal is to be *"able to transfer a user's data prior to them having to sign into the new PC"* and have those files moved to their new permanent location, the easiest solution would probably be temporarily adding the user's domain account to the `Remote Desktop Users` local group on the new machine.  It would require minimal effort on the new computer and less than five minutes of the end-user's time while they RDP into their new machine from the comfort of their own desk to create their domain user profile folder hierarchy.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: While roaming desktop profiles would be helpful, that decision is one that is above my head to make. I'm curious if this can be done without having the user sign in. When a desktop is replaced and I already have all of the user's information saved awaiting the arrival of their new desktop, it would simplify (even if just a little) my workflow to have the ability to have their PC completely ready when I go to swap out their existing machine with their replacement machine.

Comment: I was just curious if this was a possibility. Is there a way to make this happen without the use of roaming accounts.

Comment: *"Is there a way to make this happen without the use of roaming accounts?"*  Did you take a look at what I mentioned in my previous post about having the user RDP into the new machine to create their new profile folder hierarchy?  To clarify, this isn't using roaming accounts.  It is simple, two-step process to create their permanent profile folder on the new computer.

Comment: I'm trying to have everything happen without having to have the user do anything.

Comment: Needless to say it's your choice, but it sounds like you are trying to devote an extraordinary amount of time and effort in an attempt to *"...have everything happen without having to have the user do anything."*  That is an admirable sentiment, but unless your organization is willing to implement an elaborate system of roaming profiles, that philosophy might be unrealistic.  In my experience, the typical end-user really doesn't mind devoting less than five minutes of their time performing a quick login (remotely or not) in order to save 30-45 minutes copying all their files to a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Join the computer to the domain.
2. Login as a local admin
3. Go into Control >> System >> Advanced system settings >> User Profiles - [Settings...]
4. Select the user account from the old system, click [Copy To...]
5. Under "Copy profile to", put the path as `C:/Users/user.DOMAIN`.
6. Under Permitted to use, click [Change] and then [Advanced...], type the user's name or email, click [Find Now], and then select the right account before pressing [OK], then [OK] again, then [OK] again, again, and again until all of the windows are closed.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/75160/372623

Done!